# Word meaning doing something just cause you can or have the abilitity to do it

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the act of doing something without a real logical reason but just because they can. A example of what I'm talking about would be like this:

> The boy hacked the Pentagon just because he could. He didn't steal anything and he didn't want the attention; he just wanted to proclaim his own self-dignity.

What would you call someone like that or the act of doing something like that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps are you talking about someone who do things **spontaneously**.
Extreme cases are simple-minded,  autistic or genius.
The root of this behaviour may be intuition, which is more common.
**Gratuitously** of Graffito seems the best,
or in this example : "you're male... and therefore more **innately** qualified."

Comment: My first thought was **impulsively**,  which is pretty similar to your answer.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Spontaneously implies something that occurs immediately and often times without warning, it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a whim and you could argue that most often it does not. Impulsively is a much better answer.

Answer (score 8):

While not a single word, the idiomatic **[for the hell of it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+hell+of+it)** seems to convey your intended meaning quite nicely:

> Also, for the heck of it; just for the hell of it. For no particular reason; on a whim. For example, We drove by the old place just for the hell of it. In the first variant, heck is a euphemism for hell. [First half of 1900s]
>
> if you do something for the hell of it, you do it only because you want to, or because you think it is funny I decided to dye my hair bright green, just for the hell of it.

Comment: Yea for the hell of it would be a very accurate phrase to what im trying to describe , i've done some research  looking in dictionary , googling words and a very close word ive come up with is indifferent. i dont really know tell me what you think.

Comment: how about "just because" ? We drove past it just because.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **gratuitously**

> Definition: being done in a manner not demanded by the circumstances,
>   without apparent reason, cause, or justification.

Example: *Seven soldiers on patrol in south area killed an innocent teenager in a gratuitously violent attack using rifle butts, helmets, fists and feet*.